# postgreSQL　functionでエラーになってしまう

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testtable()
RETURNS void AS
'
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 2..41 LOOP
    FOR j IN 1..5 LOOP
        IF j = 1  THEN
            INSERT INTO a(test1, test2) VALUES(i,1);
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO b(test3, test4) VALUES(i,j);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP ;
  COMMIT;
END;
'
 LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
select testtable();
```

このエラーが発生してしまいます

```
cannot begin/end transactions in PL/pgSQL
```

原因がわからなくて困っています
教えてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

関数内に`COMMIT`があるのが原因です。
エラーメッセージの通り、PostgreSQLではユーザ定義関数内でコミットやロールバックといったトランザクション制御はできません。

https://www.postgresql.jp/document/10/html/plpgsql-structure.html より:

> PL/pgSQLのBEGIN/ENDは単にまとめるためのもので、トランザクションを始めたり終わらせたりしません。 関数とトリガプロシージャは常に外側の問い合わせで確立されたトランザクションの内側で実行されます。 トランザクションの実行させる文脈はありませんので、これらはトランザクションを開始することもコミットすることもできません。

PostgreSQL 11からは`CREATE PROCEDURE`文でプロシージャを作成し`CALL`で呼ぶときはできるようになるようです。

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/plpgsql-transactions.html

Comment: commit;
を除いたら作成、実行が可能になりました。
お手数をおかけしました、ありがとうございます。